# LINQ Any() not working as expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm battling with what I thought would be a simple query...

**Schema is like**:

`Documents` (DocumentID, Name)
`Industries` (IndustryID, Name)
`Documents_Industries` (DocumentID, IndustryID)

**Data is like**:

DocA -- IndustryA
DocB -- IndustryA, IndustryB
DocC -- IndustryA, IndustryB
DocD -- IndustryB

(So the data above would result in 6 rows in `Documents_Industries`, hopefully that's self-explanatory)

**Expected behaviour**: I'm trying to show a list of Documents, filtered by the Industry(ies) a user selects. If IndustryA is selected, result set should be DocA, DocB, DocC. If IndustryB is selected, result set should be DocB, DocC, DocD. **If IndustryA and IndustryB is selected, result set should be DocB, DocC.**

**Code so far**:

```
IEnumerable<Document> docs = db.Documents.Where(l => l.IsActive == true);

// industryIdsSelected is an int[] from the user's selection

if (industryIdsSelected.Length > 0)
{
    docs = docs.Where(l => l.Industries.Any(m => industryIdsSelected.Contains(m.IndustryID)));
}
```

**Actual behaviour**: If IndustryA and IndustryB is selected, result set is DocA, DocB, DocC, DocD. Instead of just DocB, DocC.

I've tried with `.All()` but that doesn't work either. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: All would be closer but it would be more like `l => SelectedIndustries.All(m => m.Contains(...`

Comment: You are using many to many and if IndustryA and IndustryB is selected why you want to exclude document A and document B? They both have those industries.

Comment: @kat1330, because that's the requirement :). The user's filter is more AND than OR - "get all documents that have both those industries".

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, `SelectedIndustries`?

Comment: Some variable I made up that could just be your Ids

Comment: You should also be able to use `db.Industries.Where(industryIdsSelected ...).SelectMany(i => i.Documents)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use both `All` and `Any` like this:

```
docs.Where(l => industryIdsSelected.All(x => l.Industries.Any(m => m.IndustryID == x)));
```

Comment: You beat me by a few seconds. I was going to add that this is OK as long as `industryIdsSelected` is not a "long" list, because EF must convert the list into a temp table (of sorts) in the SQL statement. But I think it's OK here.

Comment: You'll see when you inspect the generated SQL. The list is reconstructed by `n` select + union statements.

Comment: @GertArnold - Good point. Based on the example, I would guess there shouldn't be an issue for the OP.

Comment: @Aducci, how do you think in LINQ like that? Trial and error or RTFM?

Comment: @GertArnold Actually since OP declared the variable as `IEnumerable<...>`, the filtering in question will happen in memory :)

Comment: @user982119 - A little bit of both :)

Comment: Keen-eyed Ivan on the move! I guess it should be `IQueryable`.